# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in React JS and PowerApps (Power Pages)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, powerapps

i am using react in online VS code Editor and facing several issues

1. Script type = (i used text/babel) then changed to (text/javascript) and now to type = module
2. getting these errors Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at (index):542:33)
   (index):446 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at (index):446:7)

i have given the whole code.. FOR more information i am working on power apps and trying to create power pages in React and facing too much issues.. Don't Know how to fix it ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module">
      import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js';
      import ReactDOM from 'https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js';

      const App = () => {
        const [changeImpactDetailList, setChangeImpactDetailList] = useState([]);

        useEffect(() => {
          const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
              const requestBody = {
                changeimpactId: '03d60dbf-a3c9-ed11-b595-6045bdd0ef3b',
                PageNo: 1
              };
              const response = await fetch(
                'url-removed',
                {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
                }
              );

              if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
              }

              const data = await response.json();

              if (data && data.ChangeImpactDetail && data.ChangeImpactDetail.length > 0) {
                setChangeImpactDetailList(data.ChangeImpactDetail);
              } else {
                setChangeImpactDetailList([]);
              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error:', error);
            }
          };

          fetchData();
        }, []);

        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Change Impact Details</h1>
            <ul>
              {changeImpactDetailList.map((item, index) => (
                <li key={index}>
                  <p>changeimpactdetailid: {item.crmk_changeimpactdetailid}</p>
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      };

      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

i have given the whole code.. FOR more information i am working on power apps and trying to create power pages in React and facing too much issues.. Don't Know how to fix it ?